# itemBulder jump to next item

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a novice programmer,

In `itembuilder` how I can jump to next index item?

```
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: s.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index){
          if(s.data[index]["count"].toString() == "0") return new Text('');

          image1 = s.data[index]["image"];
          if(image1 == null){
            image2 = imageSrc;
          }else{
            image2 = s.data[index]["image"]["src"];
            print(s.data[index]);
          }
```

I used

```
if(s.data[index]["count"].toString() == "0") return new Text('');
```

but, the space between the items is created.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to skip certain items. If you're on Dart 2.3+, you can use `collection if` or `collection for` to do this. But, the simplest way of doing this in your use case is to replace `Text('')` with `const SizedBox()`. There will be a widget in a widget tree, but with 0 height/width, it will not show up on screen and take any space, and as a `const` widget it should not rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Try to return a [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) or [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) which don't take any space,

```
 if(s.data[index]["count"].toString() == "0") return Container(width: 0,height: 0,);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood correctly, you want to skip the build for items where `count` is zero.

Keeping that code you could return a `SizedBox.shrink()` instead of a `Text('')`, which is a zero-sized container.

A better approach would be filter `s.data` and use that in your `ListView.builder`:

```
List<?> filteredData = s.data.where((item) => item["count"].toString() != 0).toList();
```

where `?` stands for the type of your data.

I don't know why you're using `toString`, if `count` is an integer a better approach would be:

```
List<?> filteredData = s.data.where((item) => item["count"] != 0).toList();
```

and then replace `s.data` with `filteredData` in your `ListView.builder`